# Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I was trying to upgrade VLC player on my Ubuntu 14.04. Below are the commands I've executed. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version) But facing issues like Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file. I'v tried multiple solutions but not able to fix it. Please help.

[image]

[image]

After going through multiple forums, I did tried to add this line

> deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

But it was already present on my machine. Mine is a 64 bit OS.

Now I've also completely purged Google chrome from my machine. But still the issue persists. Not able to install VLC/Google chrome either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning that you see is caused by Google's dropping of support for 32-bit Google Chrome for Linux. You can fix that by looking at https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error.

However, the aforementioned warning you see is entirely unrelated to your attempt to upgrade `vlc`. Looking at https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily, the PPA you added does not have an installation candidate for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr). If you want to use this PPA, you are going to have to upgrade to 15.10, 16.04 or 16.10. I would recommend 16.04 because 16.04 is an LTS while 15.10 will reach end-of-life in a couple of weeks and 16.10 is a developmental version that may be too unstable for you.

If you want to keep using 14.04, then you can simply remove the PPA and just install `vlc` from the Ubuntu repositories, but this version will be outdated relative to what is available to in the PPA.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

replace:

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

with:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Comment: This is worked, _until_ next update overwrite it to default setting. This is even say, `### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ### # You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.`